# What is a JSF view?

Tags: jsf

Recently in one of my classes, my Professor went over the basics of setting up a very basic Java Web Application program in NetBeans. After we created the project, the index.xthml file opened and we were told it is a JSF page. However my Professor kept using the term "JSF views" when we were going through the index. What exactly is a "JSF view"?

Comment: I would guess your professor is using an alternative name for a facelet. That xhtml file handles the view part of MVC.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks for your input. Your suggestion made the most sense, so I went with that.

Comment: @rze In addition to MarsAtomic's comment, the name "JSF view" is used also by the JSF specification to indicate a JSF page

Comment: @Tarik, thanks that makes sense after looking into it further.